# Forcing POS tags in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp, part-of-speech

Is there a way to process an already POS-tagged text using Stanford CoreNLP?

For example, I have the sentence in this format

```
They_PRP are_VBP hunting_VBG dogs_NNS ._.
```

and I'd like to annotate with lemma, ner, parse, etc. by forcing the given POS annotation.

**Update.** I tried this code, but it's not working.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma"); 

StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
String sentText = "They_PRP are_VBP hunting_VBG dogs_NNS ._.";
List<CoreLabel> sentence = new ArrayList<>();

String[] parts = sentText.split("\\s");
for (String p : parts) {
    String[] split = p.split("_");
    CoreLabel clToken = new CoreLabel();
    clToken.setValue(split[0]);
    clToken.setWord(split[0]);
    clToken.setOriginalText(split[0]);
    clToken.set(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class, split[1]);
    sentence.add(clToken);
}
Annotation s = new Annotation(sentText);
s.set(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class, sentence);

Annotation document = new Annotation(s);
pipeline.annotate(document);
```

Comment: I tried the solutions posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245422/stanford-corenlp-use-partial-existing-annotation?rq=1) but when I execute `pipeline.annotate(document);` the POS tags have changed.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working" ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `parse` annotator can change part of speech annotations. Does the problem persist if you remove the parse annotator?

Comment: I'm not using `parse` at all. I want to add lemma. Anyway, by "it's not working' I mean that the pipeline will parse the sentence from scratch, changing the POS I attached to it.

Comment: OK. Can you also show the code you're using to instantiate the pipeline (`StanfordCoreNLP` object)?

Comment: `Properties props = new Properties();`
`props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");`
`StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POS annotations will certainly be replaced if you include the `pos` annotator in the pipeline.

Instead, remove the `pos` annotator and add the option `-enforceRequirements false`. This will allow the pipeline to run even though an annotator which `lemma`, etc. depend on (the `pos` annotator) is not present. Add the following line before pipeline instantiation:

```
props.setProperty("enforceRequirements", "false");
```

Of course, behavior is undefined if you venture into this area without setting the proper annotations, so make sure you match the annotations made by the relevant annotator ([`POSTaggerAnnotator`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/POSTaggerAnnotator.java#L142) in this case).

Comment: This sounds good: how can I set such option using CoreNLP inside a Java project?